# .NET show english numbers while os regional settings arabic

Tags: .net

I am building a .NET windows application and facing a problem with displaying numbers while the OS regional settings region is Arabic. OS enforce my application to show numbers in arabic too.

I tried to use `Globalization.CultureInfo` to change this behaviour, but it's not working.

Comment: You haven't shown what you've tried - *how* you've tried to use CultureInfo.

Comment: @JonSkeet At leas the obvious attempt of passing another culture (such as `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA")`) to `int.ToString` without specifying a format string returns the same string as `InvariantCulture` does.

Comment: @mohammad Can you post the expected output for some example? I'm not familiar with arabic, so I don't know how numbers should look like.

Comment: please try this case. On your windows OS, set the regioanl language to be Arabic(Saudi Arabia). on your .net create a new form with label control and set this label text to be "label1.text=1254" and run the application. the number you will see is in arabic shape, and this is my question, how can i force it to be always in english format.